# Generic Collection of T sub not working

Tags: vb.net, generics

I'm trying to teach myself generics and trying to create a generic list(of T).  T in this case would be an object class that I've defined.  Everything seems to be working fine until I try to set a property within the generic type.

I get "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" at this line here.
`tType.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(ListItemObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)`

This is the sub I am inheriting within my T object. So I would call it like this. T.GetCollectionFromDB(), and then it will set T(me) with the collection data.  I can't figure out why I am getting the object reference error.  Perhaps you experienced professionals can let me know why.  Thanks in advance.

```
    Public Overloads Sub GetCollectionFromDB(ByVal ID As Integer)
        Try
            Dim BaseObject As New Object
            Dim tType As Type = GetType(t)
            Dim ListCollection As New List(Of t)
            Dim ListItemObject As Object
            Dim BaseType As Type = MyBase.GetType()
            Dim TableName As String = String.Empty
            Dim SQL As New LottoPayload.DataHandler.SQLiDataClass
            Dim SQLString As String = String.Empty
            Dim SQLCommand As SQLiteCommand = Nothing
            Dim SQLConnection As SQLiteConnection = Nothing
            Dim SQLiteDRObj As SQLiteDataReader = Nothing
            Dim SQLResultsTable As New DataTable

            'Create an instance of the base object
            BaseObject = Activator.CreateInstance(BaseType)
            'Get the tablename from the object
            If Not BaseObject Is Nothing Then
                TableName = BaseType.GetProperty("TableName").GetValue(BaseObject, Nothing).ToString
                If Not TableName Is Nothing Then
                    SQLString = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE GameID = '" & ID.ToString & "'"
                    SQLConnection = SQL.GetSqlConnection()

                    SQLConnection.Open()
                    SQLCommand = New SQLiteCommand(SQLConnection)
                    SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLString

                    SQLiteDRObj = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

                    SQLResultsTable.Load(SQLiteDRObj)
                    If SQLResultsTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each Row As DataRow In SQLResultsTable.Rows
                            'Create a new object
                            ListItemObject = Activator.CreateInstance(tType)
                            For Each Column As DataColumn In Row.Table.Columns

                                Dim ColumnName As String = Column.ColumnName.ToString
                                'Console.WriteLine(Row.Item(ColumnName))
                                Dim ColumnValue As Object = Row.Item(ColumnName)
                                'Console.WriteLine(Column.DataType.Name & "    ")
                                Select Case Column.DataType.Name
                                    Case "Int64"
                                        Dim ConvertedValue As Integer
                                        Integer.TryParse(ColumnValue.ToString, ConvertedValue)
                                        tType.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(ListItemObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                                    Case "Double"
                                        Dim ConvertedValue As Double
                                        Double.TryParse(ColumnValue.ToString, ConvertedValue)
                                        tType.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(ListItemObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                                    Case "String"
                                        Dim ConvertedValue As String
                                        ConvertedValue = ColumnValue.ToString
                                        tType.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(ListItemObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)
                                    Case Else
                                        Dim ConvertedValue As String
                                        ConvertedValue = "NotSet"
                                        tType.GetProperty(ColumnName).SetValue(ListItemObject, ConvertedValue, Nothing)

                                End Select

                            Next

                            ListCollection.Add(DirectCast(ListItemObject, t))
                            ListItemObject = Nothing
                        Next

                    End If


                    SQLiteDRObj.Close()
                    SQLConnection.Close()
                    SQLConnection.Dispose()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using Reflection in the first place?  If you want to learn about Generics then learn about Generics first.  Using Reflection with Generics is a step further.

Comment: As for the NullReferenceException, as always, determine which reference is null first of all.

Comment: The shortest distance between two points is a straight line. I know where I need to be.  Now I'm trying to get there.  I dont feel that I'm using "T" properly, and everything I read doesn't show you in generic form. It automatically assumes you know the type.

Comment: I think that you're trying to use Generics in an unusual situation, i.e. with Reflection, without understanding how Generics work.  It looks like you are trying to write a method that will create a collection of items where the type of the items is a class written to correspond to a database table and you want to be able to call that method for any table in your database, correct?